# VBA function = function argument?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is an example function with a switch statement, however I'm having a hard time understanding how a function can equal an argument provided?

```
Function getnumber(value, method) As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim rtn As String
    j = 0
    Select Case method
    Case 0:


    getnumber = value


    Case 1:
        rtn = ""
        For i = 1 To Len(value)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(value, i, 1)) Then
                j = j + 1
                rtn = rtn & Mid(value, i, 1)
            Else
                If j > 3 Then Exit For
                j = 0
                rtn = ""
            End If
        Next
        If rtn = "" Then getnumber = "" Else getnumber = rtn
    Case Else:
        MsgBox ("Invalid method in getnumber")
    End Select
End Function
```

"getnumber = value" is really confusing me.  Where *getnumber* is the function and value is an argument of the *getnumber* function

Any ideas?

Comment: `getnumber = value` is the return value - the calling code will receive `value` if it calls `getnumber(value, method)`.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but your function lacks a lot of dimensioning of variables. `Dim i, j As Integer` should be `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer`, value and method should be dimensioned too (I think `As Variant` or `As String` and `As Integer`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VBA, you assign the return value of a function with the syntax `YourFunctionName = ValueToReturn`.

Therefore, `getnumber = value` simply sets `value` as the value to be returned from the function.